# Powershell - Is a time within a Time range?

Tags: powershell

I' running a Powershell scrip that runs an AWS S3 backup. I need to find if the current time is within a time range.  If time between 12 pm and 1 pm $CurrRun = 'NoonBackup'

Comment: what have you tried? this is pretty basic ... so i wonder what went wrong. [*grin*]

Comment: I am very new to this. Never used Powershell before.  I tried doing some Google searches but to no avail. Most likely because I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: it's usually a REALLY good idea to show what you tried - even if it didn't work as expected. [*grin*] ///// however, this is within my limited skill set ... so i put in an Answer. i think i explained what is going on. please ask if it needs a bit more "why/what".

Answer (score 0):

here's one method to determine if a file was last written to in a specific hour range. the test ignores the date, so if that is needed, you will need to update the code.

what it does ...

- creates the constants to be used
- gets a file to work with
  on my system at this time, the `[0]` file has the LWT hour = 12p [1200 hours]. the `[-1]` file has the LWT hour set to 5p [1700 hours].
- checks to see if the LWT hour is in the required range
- if yes, it writes that to the screen
  you would put your "what to do if yes" code there. [*grin*]
- if no, it writes a warning msg

the code ...

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = '*.log'
$TargetHourRange = 12..13

# on my system right now ...
#    the [0] file has "LastWriteTime" set to "12:33 PM"
#    the [-1] file has "LastWriteTime" set to "5:28 PM"
$1stFile = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter $Filter -File)[0]

if ($1stFile.LastWriteTime.Hour -in $TargetHourRange)
    {
    'The LastWriteTime [ {0} ] of the file is in the required range [ {1} ].' -f $1stFile.LastWriteTime, "$TargetHourRange"
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Warning (    '{0} is out of range.' -f $1stFile.LastWriteTime)
    }
```

output with the 1200 hours file ...

```
The LastWriteTime [ 2020-04-21 12:33:51 PM ] of the file is in the required range [ 12 13 ].
```

output with the 1700 hours file ...

```
WARNING: 2020-04-27 5:28:48 PM is out of range.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input Lee.
The problem was how to know if the scrip was called at 12:30 pm or 11:30 pm. So I wanted to check if the time was between 12 pm and 1 pm to be safe. The result was much easier than I expected since all I need is the 12 pm hour in 24 hour format (HH). 12 hour format is (hh).

$CurrRun = 'NightBackup'
$CurrHour = Get-Date -Format HH
if ($CurrHour -eq 12 )
{$CurrRun = 'NoonBackup'}

$CurrRun

Comment: glad to know you got it working as needed. [*grin*] i managed to entirely miss your intent ... [*blush*]